# Curve fitting on Lua

Tags: lua, curve, gaussian

I'm looking for algorithms to do curve fitting from tabular XY data to a Gaussian function (a.k.a. bell curve). By googling I can find few gaussian fitting algos for Matlab, here are couple of them:

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Fitting_Gaussian_Data.html

http://jila.colorado.edu/bec/BEC_for_everyone/matlabfitting.htm

One seems to use 'polyfit' function of Matlab for the job.

Anyone seen readily made algo for Lua language (either gaussian or polyfit)? If not, I would greatly appreciate one's help for creating/porting such algorithm as it would probably consume a day with my limited Lua skills.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt to extract gaussian fit out of noisy measurement data.

```
require 'gsl'
require 'math'

--x=x coordinates, y=y coordinates
--clip=relative clip/ignore level 0..1 (i.e 0.1 removes values below 10% of max amplitide)
--removeoffset=set to true if y data offset should be removed
function gaussianFit( x, y, clip, removeoffset )
    local xx = {}
    local yy = {}
    local yoffset=0

    if removeoffset==nil or removeoffset==false then
    else --remove y data offset
        yoffset=gsl.Vector(y):min()
    end

    local ymax=gsl.Vector(y):max()-yoffset

    --pick only data points that has y coord larger than clip level
    for i=1,#x do
        if (y[i]-yoffset) > (clip*ymax) then
            table.insert(xx, x[i])
            table.insert(yy, math.log(y[i]-yoffset))
        end
    end

    local xvect = gsl.Vector(xx)
    local yvect = gsl.Vector(yy)

    --fit to polynomial
    local poly3 = gsl.fit.poly(3) -- a third degree polynomial
    local fit = gsl.lsfit({xvect, poly3}, yvect, nil, "fmulti") -- fits xx and yy with poly3

    --convert to gauss coeffs
    local A2=fit:coeffs()[3]
    local A1=fit:coeffs()[2]
    local A0=fit:coeffs()[1]

    local sigma=math.sqrt(-1/(2*A2))
    local mu=A1*math.pow(sigma,2)
    local A=math.exp(A0+math.pow(mu,2)/(2*math.pow(sigma,2)))

    return sigma, mu, A
end

xx={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
yy={1, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1}
sigma,mu,A=gaussianFit(xx,yy,0.1,false)
print(sigma.." "..mu.." ".. A)
--prints 2.2829275461334 4.6387484511153 4.201115115886
```

Comment: I got `module 'gsl' not found`. Do you know how can I install it on Ubuntu 19.04?

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange the equation to a linear form, and then use the methods described in [Linear Regression](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) by Paul Bourke (a little down the page).

If you need, I can demonstrate the rearranging process for you.

If you *really* need, I can provide an implementation of the line-of-best-fit algorithm in Lua.

Comment: If you do not mind, I would like to see this rearranging process. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I managed to make some sort of implementation with fitting functions of GSL. I estimated it right, it took almost a day to pull it together including gsl-lua tweaking to get it running under Windows. I'll post the code in here.